# How to parse StackExchange OAuth response?

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm trying to integrate with [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and I'm almost done. I successfully got the code from steps 1-3 and now requesting the access token via the following method:

```
def get_token(self, code):
    api_response = requests.post(
        url=self.TOKEN_URL,
        data={
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri,
        },
        headers={'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    )
    return api_response.text
```

The method returns a string like:

```
access_token=abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234&expires=86399
```

which I struggle to parse. Is there a handy way in Python to get the access_token value from this string, without invoking regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. The `urlparse` module contains the `parse_qs` function, which takes the querystring and returns a dictionary:

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qs('access_token=abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234&expires=86399')
{'access_token': ['abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234'], 'expires': ['86399']}
```

However, I do wonder why you're not using a full Python OAuth client library - there are various, such as [Google's](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth), that will do the whole thing for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that solutions exist, but I'm learning Python and doing such things myself is very insightful.